# Correct torque settings for Polaris connectors

Tags: aluminum-wiring

I am connecting 6 awg aluminum wires and 10 awg copper wires with a Polaris connector for my new cooktop.  What are the correct torque settings?

Comment: why don't you refer to the manufacturer's documentation?

Comment: Who made the connectors in question?

Answer (score 1):

The torque range will be based on the wire and the connector size, I have the chart printed out so my guys use the right value. #4 connector with #6 wire = 35 in lbs, #10 wire= 15 in lbs.
Connector 1/0 #6 wire= 55 in lbs , #10 wire =25 in lbs.
If you have a different size connector it may not be rated for the wire sizes you have. I printed the chart out several years back but torque values don’t change.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider using a bi-metal connector like one of these:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/AlumiConn-2-Port-Al-Cu-Wire-Connector-25-Pack-95025/204958913?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CVF%7CD27E%7C27-11_TOOLS_%26_ACCESSORIES%7CNA%7CPLA%7c71700000033101173%7c58700003868916496%7c92700031090205821&gclid=CjwKCAjwqZPrBRBnEiwAmNJsNpYT_0CoS-n3l92T4SHlOz76ZT-zTWW-JYJIi-9P3oE-GE0ouv_6hRoCdX0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

if the Polaris connector you refer to is not specifically designed for bi-metal.

Comment: AlumiConns aren't nearly chunky enough for 6AWG, and most insulated mechanical connectors and splices in North America *are* AlxCu listed/rated, as well.

Comment: I have 6 different types of Polaris lugs on my shelf. Some are copper only, some are copper aluminum the same as any other system. The op needs to verify the AL9CU listing because the fine wire lugs are copper only it is molded on the part. But I would use Polaris any day over alumacons.